How to Stop ECS Tasks and Underlying EC2 Instances Using Boto3 Without Fargate?
I have deployed tasks on ECS using the EC2 launch type (not Fargate), and I do not want to use Fargate.
Currently, I can stop the ECS tasks by setting the desired count to 0 using the update_service method in Boto3:
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ecs')

response = client.update_service(
    cluster='my-cluster',
    service='my-service',
    desiredCount=0
)

While this stops the tasks, the underlying EC2 instances remain running and continue to incur costs. I would like to stop those EC2 instances as well using Boto3.
How can I automate stopping or terminating the EC2 instances associated with the ECS cluster after stopping the tasks?

By using Boto3 you can stops the tasks, then identifies the EC2 instances, and finally terminates those instances.
import boto3

# initialize clients
ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs')
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

def stop_ecs_tasks_and_instances(cluster_name, service_name):
    # stop ECS tasks
    ecs_client.update_service(
        cluster=cluster_name,
        service=service_name,
        desiredCount=0
    )
    print("Tasks stopped")

    # get container EC2 instances
    container_instances = ecs_client.list_container_instances(cluster=cluster_name)['containerInstanceArns']

    if not container_instances:
        print("No container instances found in the cluster")
        return

    # describe the container instances to get the EC2 instance IDs
    container_details = ecs_client.describe_container_instances(
        cluster=cluster_name,
        containerInstances=container_instances
    )
    ec2_instance_ids = [
        container['ec2InstanceId']
        for container in container_details['containerInstances']
    ]
    # terminate EC2 instances
    print("Terminating EC2 instances...")
    ec2_client.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=ec2_instance_ids)
    print("EC2 instances terminated.")

# provide your ECS cluster name and service name
cluster_name = 'my-cluster'
service_name = 'my-service'

stop_ecs_tasks_and_instances(cluster_name, service_name)

One small note, if your ECS cluster is part of an Auto Scaling group, you may need to suspend the scaling processes before terminating instances. You can use the autoscaling Boto3 client to do this as following: 
import boto3

# initialize the Auto Scaling client
autoscaling_client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

def scale_down_asg(asg_name):
    try:
        autoscaling_client.update_auto_scaling_group(
            AutoScalingGroupName=asg_name,
            MinSize=0,
            DesiredCapacity=0
        )
        print(f"ASG '{asg_name}' scaled down successfully. All EC2 instances will be terminated.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error scaling down ASG '{asg_name}': {e}")

# provide your ASG name
asg_name = 'your-asg-name'

scale_down_asg(asg_name)


Thank you for the response sabil
Instead of manually terminating the EC2 instances after reducing the desired count of tasks to 0, can I achieve the same result by reducing the MinSize of the Auto Scaling Group (ASG) to 0 using the update_auto_scaling_group method in Boto3?
autoscaling_client = boto3.client('autoscaling')
autoscaling_client.update_auto_scaling_group(
AutoScalingGroupName='your-asg-name',
MinSize=0,
DesiredCapacity=0
)
Would this approach automatically handle the termination of the underlying EC2 instances?

Yes, reducing the MinSize and DesiredCapacity of the Auto Scaling Group (ASG) to 0 using the update_auto_scaling_group method in Boto3 will automatically terminate the EC2 instances managed by the ASG.

Thanks for confirming will test this approach using the update_auto_scaling_group method and see how it works. Appreciate your input

No problem. I also update my answer and add a sample script for that. You can give a try.
